# Unity Firebase Plugin throws "DllNotFoundException: App" in Android logcat and stucks at this point

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

Currently I'm trying to implement the Unity FirebaseAnalytics Plugin for my android game. I implement this firebase code into the start function:

```
DependencyStatus dependencyStatus = DependencyStatus.UnavailableOther;

    FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
    {

        dependencyStatus = task.Result;
        if (dependencyStatus == DependencyStatus.Available)
        {

            FirebaseAnalytics.SetAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);

        }
        else
        {

            Debug.LogError(
              "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: " + dependencyStatus);
        }

    });
```

So when I test my app on Android I use the android Logcat to check if there is any error. And logcat throws this error below and then the game stucks:

> DllNotFoundException: App
>   03-16 20:57:56.768  1564  1584 E Unity   :   at (wrapper managed-to-native) Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper:SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_AppUtil (Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegat

I found some threads about this error but nothing helps. I guess that the plugin is missing some files or while importing something gone wrong. Because in another project of me there are more files in the Plugin/Android directory.

This is my current Plugin Folder
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQShh.png)

This is my Plugin folder of an another project
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXUUU.png)

So in the older project there are more folders and .aars and .jars. I thought my android sdk is broken but after I installed again the same issue appears. I currently use the newest Android SDK and all required libarys and components for android development. My Firebase Version is Version 4.4.3. I use the JDK Version 8u162. Working with Unity 2017.3.1f1.

So is this that normal? Because I guess the Dll Exceptions depends on this problem because some files are missing.

Comment: I tested the plugin on antother machine and it imports more files as on my machine. So I get always this error in the Unity Console "Gradle failed fetch dependencies". And Unity trys to install the m2repository but failes. On the other machine nothing of them happened the plugin works well without any errors. Has anyone an idea why my machine doesnt put that files into my directory?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this post is already closed, but I would like to pass on my experience, I had the same problem, and I was able to solve it as follows.
After you export the Unity3d project to Android Studio, convert it to module

" 
Removing the project's applicationId in build.gradle
Changing com.android.application to com.android.library in build.gradle "

1 - Copy the .aar files from the .libs folder of the module project, if the master project does not already have them
2 - include the .aar files in build.gradle

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree (include: ['* .jar', '* .aar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project (': ModuleApp') 
}

3 - Copy the file "google-services.xml" to the res / values / google-services.xml folder of the master project
4 - Ready, Firebase will work with the sources of the module exported from Unity

Sorry for my bad english